# Ruby: Throwing undefined method error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods

Running a statement like this:

```
self.user.email || self.organization.email || nil
```

Ruby throws the error `undefined method 'email' for nil:NilClass`, but it should just return `nil` instead. What am I doing wrong here?

Does it occur because in some cases `user` || `organization` is `nil`?

Comment: yes, you're right, is some cases `user == nil` or `organization == nil`

Comment: @IgorDrozdov But then I'd expect it to just jump to the next option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In  `self.user.email`, if `self.user` is nill, then you can't call `email` on it.

If you're using Ruby 2.3 or newer, you can use the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/):

```
self.user&.email || self.organization&.email
```

Note the `|| nil` at the end is probably unneccesary.

If you don't want to introduce a dependency to Ruby 2.3 or newer, you could use [Object#try](https://apidock.com/rails/v3.2.1/Object/try) from ActiveSupport (included with Rails):

```
self.user.try(:email) || self.organization.try(:email)
```

Comment: Didn't know about the safe navigation operator - nice!

Comment: @jonhue also note that the `self` here is unnecessary, unless you've defined a local variable `user` in addition to the method with the same name.

Answer (score 2):

The following code does what you're expecting:

```
user && user.email || organization && organization.email
```

If you're using `ruby >= 2.3.0`, there's null propagation feature:

```
user&.email || organization&.email
```

Comment: another option is to do user.try(:email) || organization.try(:email). https://apidock.com/rails/NilClass/try  also the self is probably redundant

Comment: @NatanRubinstein Providing we developing Rails app. Then I'd suggest using `NilClass#try!`

Answer (score 0):

Yes the error occurs when the user/organization is nil. It tries to get email from a nil class. So you can add conditions like `user.present? || organization.present?`. Get the email after passing through condition. If the condition fails have it as nil.

Comment: So not possible without conditions?

Comment: Not necessarily. You can use "try" as @max said.

Answer (score 0):

Just out of curiosity:

```
[user, organization].compact.map(&:email).compact.first
```

or, for Ruby2.3+

```
[user, organization].compact.map(&:email).detect(&:itself)
```